# Unable to write test case in Junit 5

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, microservices, junit5, testcase

This is my Globalexceptionhandlerclass.java. I am trying to write JUnit 5 test cases, but getting stuck. Can anyone help me on this please?

```java
Globalexceptionhandlerclass.java


import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;
            
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
    protected final Log loger = LogFactory.getLog(ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.class);
                
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    ResponseEntity<?> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request ) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        result.put("date", new Date());
        result.put("message", ex.getMessage());
        result.put("details", request.getDescription(true));
            
        loger.error(ex);
                    
        ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = ResponseEntity.badRequest()
            .header("exception-erro", "error")
            .body(result);
                    
        return responseEntity;
        
    }
            
 }
```

This is my `GlobalExceptionHandlerTest.java`. I got stuck on this, it is failing. I tried other things but it is not working. The last two lines are failing, I don't know why. Anyone please help me to corect this cases. It will be very helpful to me.

```java
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ExceptionHandlerControllerAdviceTest {
    
    /**
     * Given a handle invalid exception when controller advice then return a bad request exception.
     */
    @Test
    void handleInvalidFormatException() {
        GlobalExceptionHandler controllerAdvice = new GlobalExceptionHandler();
        ResponseEntity<?> response = controllerAdvice.handleAllExceptions(null, null);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), response.getStatusCode().value());
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`handleAllExceptions` is not null-safe because of this line `result.put("message", ex.getMessage());` and you passing `ex` with null value in your test `controllerAdvice.handleAllExceptions(null, null)`.

This test has no reason to be because Spring always provides you Exception and WebRequest. So calling `handleAllExceptions(null, null)` is not possible in Spring environment.

Comment: Guillaume Macke can u help what to do here ?

Comment: If you want to test `handleAllExceptions` with null parameters, you need to modify your production code to handle it. Add null check on `ex` and `request`. Or else, don't call `handleAllExceptions` with null parameters and give it some valid input (Mock Exception and Mock WebRequest)